# Why is my program breaking when I add a void function to the main? It works without it

Tags: c, function, for-loop, printf

I have 2 functions + my main.
One of them is a void function that "prints out instructions"
The other is the one that actually does what I want it to do.

For some reason when the play function is by itself in the main it works just fine, but as soon as I add the print instructions function, it breaks and I cannot figure out why it's doing that.

Functions:
int playGame();
void printInstructions();

`

```
int playGame()
  {
    int dice[100];
    int diceAmount, j, sum = 0;
    
    printf("How many dice would you like to roll? ");
    scanf("%d",&diceAmount);
    
    for( int i = 0; i < diceAmount; i++)
    {
        dice[j] = rand() % 6 + 1;
        sum += dice[j];
        printf("Dice %d: %d\n",i+1,dice[j]);
    } 
    printf("---------\nSum: %d", sum);
    
  }
```

`

`

```
void printInstructions()
{
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("- HOW TO WIN -\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("Your dice roll must equal 7 or 11 or else you lose.\n");
    printf("Want to test your luck?\n\n");
}
```

`

Whole thing:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int playGame();
void printInstructions();

int playGame()
  {
    int dice[100];
    int diceAmount, j, sum = 0;
    
    printf("How many dice would you like to roll? ");
    scanf("%d",&diceAmount);
    
    for( int i = 0; i < diceAmount; i++)
    {
        dice[j] = rand() % 6 + 1;
        sum += dice[j];
        printf("Dice %d: %d\n",i+1,dice[j]);
    } 
    printf("---------\nSum: %d", sum);
    
  }

int main()
  {
    printInstructions();
    playGame(); 
  }
  
  
void printInstructions()
{
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("- HOW TO WIN -\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("Your dice roll must equal 7 or 11 or else you lose.\n");
    printf("Want to test your luck?\n\n");
}
```

`

Without the printInstructions();
[image: Working]

With the printIUnstruction();
[image: Broken]

Why is it breaking?

Comment: `dice[j] = rand() % 6 + 1;` - you never initialize `j`. And I strongly suspect you meant to use `i` instead, which makes a lot more sense. Although the array in general doesn't seem to be required, you can just have a single `int` instead

Comment: Also, move main() to the end.

Comment: wow! @UnholySheep, That fixed it haha. I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I was doing wrong this whole time. This was such an easy fix... thank you

Comment: Also thank you @MartinJames, I made the change but I am unsure if that had too much of an affect on the code here. I tested it both ways (main() on the bottom and above the void function) and it seemed to work in both places. Is it just best practice to have the main() on the bottom?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestions from UnholySheep & Martin James, I was able to get my code to work.
Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int playGame();

void printInstructions()
{
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("- HOW TO WIN -\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("Your dice roll must equal 7 or 11 or else you lose.\n");
    printf("Want to test your luck?\n\n");
}

int playGame()
  {
    int dice;
    int diceAmount, sum = 0;
    
    printf("How many dice would you like to roll? ");
    scanf("%d",&diceAmount);
    
    for( int i = 0; i < diceAmount; i++)
    {
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        sum += dice;
        printf("Dice %d: %d\n",i+1,dice);
    } 
    printf("---------\nSum: %d\n",sum);
    
  }

int main()
  {
 printInstructions();
 playGame();
    
  }
```

Result:

[image: Working]